# The ambiguous error occurs while using the models.sequelize.col () in the include in sequelize(node.js express)

Tags: join, include, sequelize.js, mariadb

mariadb,

```
show tables;
Board
Comment
```

my code,

```
models.Board.findAll({
attributes: [
  '_no', 'title', 'content', 'createdAt'
],
include: [
  {
    model: models.Comment,
    tableAlias: 'Comment',
    attributes: [
      [models.sequelize.fn('count', models.sequelize.col('_no')), 'comment']
    ]
  }
],
group: ['_no', 'title', 'content', 'createdAt'],
order: [
  ['createdAt', 'DESC']
],
    raw: true
   }).then(function(boards)

     {
         res.send(JSON.stringify(boards));

      });
```

Why error occurs?

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_NON_UNIQ_ERROR: Column '_no' in field list is ambiguous
```

models.sequelize.col('_no') -> models.sequelize.col('models.Comment._no')
error, too.

models.sequelize.col ( '_ no') in the _no want to use Comment table.

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Appearently both Board and Comment have a `_no` column?  In that case you need to specify which one you want to count, fx: `models.sequelize.col('board._no'))` (make sure the table name matches the pluralization and capitalization of the table in the rest of the query)

Comment: But how to do this on a table when you don't know from where it will be included? Any clue?

Comment: @Jan, can you not give me a hint?

Comment: Did you solve it ? We have same issue my root table have full_name column the the child table is belongsTo root table that have full_name column to ... I got ambiguitas. How to ignore them ? Without refactor the column name ..

Answer (score 1):

if multiple table is there in query then you need to specify which table createdAt you want to group by because node have all table createdAt(default created)

```
group: ["your_table_name_here\".\"createdAt"]
```

if we use multiple model for get record in that case same field name in 2 or more model then you need to specify which model record you want to group by so in that case i write group: ["**your_table_name_here**"."createdAt"]

Comment: Your explanation is really difficult to understand. Please try to clean it up.

Comment: if we use multiple model for get record in that case same field name in 2 or more model then you need to specify which model record you want to group by so in that case i write group: ["your_table_name_here\".\"createdAt"]

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the model where `createdAt` is located

```
import { Parking } from "../database/models";

const parking = await Parking.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
      "$Parking.createdAt$": {
         [Op.between]: [new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate)]
      }
    }
})
```